# Where to find the Slime world?

Tags: dragon-warrior-monsters

I recently found my old Game Boy with the Dragn Warrior Monsters module and wanted to continue. As I watched at my progress, I started looking out for the Slime warp world.

There are several worlds that mostly contain monsters of one race and I want to find the one for Slimes. But I can't remember it.
On the internet I can find its alternative name (as I'm playing in German localization I don't know it's English name) but I can't find any info where to find it.

**Where can I find the portal to the Slime world?**